# Horizontal Pager of Foundation API, always go back to position 0 in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Horizontal Pager in my Composable named ScreenHome.

This is the state of this pager in viewModel

```
val pagerState = mutableStateOf(PagerState(initialPage = 0))
```

Now if I swipe my pager and then go to any other Composable screen, then whenever I comeback to this "ScreenHome" which has this pager, the pager is always on position 0 i-e showing the first item instead of showing the item where I was last time.

Comment: well, it was an issue of Pager API. It's fixed in since I started using Compose/Foundation version 1.5.0-alpha02